# Character ĵ being displayed as a black box

Tags: fonts, characters, input-encodings, tilde, esperanto

I'm writing a document in which I try to use the following characters used in Esperanto: ĉ, ĥ, ĵ, ŭ, ŝ, Ĉ, Ĥ, Ĵ, Ŭ, Ŝ.

Until now I was using base latex and it was working just fine, but I switched to a template and only the character ĵ is displayed as a black box.

The template in question in overleaf is this one: https://www.overleaf.com/articles/cpsc-542f-notes/cvptzcpvsrpn

I'm writing this document locally using Miktex/PdfLatex, although the error can be reproduced within Overleaf by importing the template and typing these characters. It looks as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to make that character work within that template?

Comment: Please don't post links to Overleaf templates. Not all of us have or want Overleaf accounts. If you can find, e.g., a git repo for the source of the template, that's much better.

Comment: I don't use Overleaf myself, I opened the account just to test this over there, and I thought it would be easier to share that way. This template is a variation of the [Legrand orange book](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/legrand-orange-book) that I used for other projects strictly math related. I tried the same thing in with that template and the same issue happened. It's my first time postinte in TeX StackExchange, so I'll keep this in mind for possible future questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}

ĉ, ĥ, ĵ, ŭ, ŝ, Ĉ, Ĥ, Ĵ, Ŭ, Ŝ.
\end{document}
```

`mathptmx` is a very old package targeting fonts available on a 1990s laser printer

replace it by a more modern Times Roman clone such as `newtx`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

ĉ, ĥ, ĵ, ŭ, ŝ, Ĉ, Ĥ, Ĵ, Ŭ, Ŝ.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The pointed me in the right direction to solve the issue. While I couldn't use that particular package, I could get around using some other package. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}`